# Clojure, Java Interop and proxy-ed methods

Tags: clojure, interop

So, let's say I have this abstract class in Java named MyFunction, that has an abstract evaluate method.

To use this in clojure, I can do:

```
(def java-function
 (proxy [MyJavaFunction] []
   (evaluate [x]
     (* x 2))))
```

And then call it with:

```
 (.evaluate java-function 3)
```

returning

```
 ; => 6
```

What would be a nice way of turning the above into something more clojure:

```
  (java-function 3)
```

that would also be returning

```
 ; => 6
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish that by implementing the `clojure.lang.IFn` interface:

```
((proxy [clojure.lang.IFn] []
  (invoke [x]
    (str "A very a nice x indeed: " x)))
 3)
;= "A very a nice x indeed: 3"
```

To have your proxy subclass `MyFunction` and implement `IFn`, mention them both in the first argument to proxy; NB. the class goes first:

```
(proxy [MyFunction clojure.lang.IFn] []
  ...)
```

Actually the above implementation is incomplete – you'll also want to implement the `applyTo` method that takes a single seq argument apart from `this` and is used by `apply`. There are also separate `invoke` methods for other fixed arities (up to 20). Follow [this link](https://github.com/clojure/data.avl/blob/data.avl-0.0.12/src/main/clojure/clojure/data/avl.clj#L1038) to data.avl's sources (release 0.0.12) to see an `applyTo` implementation delegating to the appropriate `invoke` method while taking care to avoid going into an infinite loop / taking an inordinate amount of time if the seq that was passed in happens to be infinite / very long.